# plots don't work in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am unable to display images in iPython from matplotlib, an image appears for a split of a second in a pop up window instead of inline and then closes immediately. nothing appears in the iPython console which is inside Spyder.

```
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
xs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=np.float64)
ys = np.array([5,4,6,5,6,7], dtype=np.float64)

def best_fit_slop_and_intercept (xs,ys):
    m = ( ((mean(xs)*mean(ys))-mean(xs*ys)) /
         ((mean(xs)**2)-mean(xs**2)) )
    b = mean(ys)-m*mean(xs)
    return m,b

m,b = best_fit_slop_and_intercept(xs,ys)
print (m,b)

regression_line = [m*x + b for x in xs ]

print (regression_line)

predict_x = 9
predict_y = predict_x*m + b

plt.scatter(predict_x,predict_y, color = 'g')
plt.scatter(xs,ys)
plt.plot(xs, regression_line)
plt.show()
```

Comment: did try running this in ipython (without spyder)? I dont have spyder but this code runs fine for me. (pops a window open and stays until i exit)

Answer (score 0):

You can type `%matplotlib inline` inside the iPython console to generate your plots within the console inside spyder. You can also type `%matplotlib qt`to get an interactive window.

Your code snippet works for me with both settings. Failing that you can go to [preferences>iPython console>Graphics>Graphics backend] to adjust the graphics defaults and settings to see if that fixes the problem.